# How to unwind segues from UIAlertView button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I have 3 view controllers. The first is presented modally from my root view controller.

They are in a navigation stack using `push` from first to third.

My final view controller (third) has a `UIAlertView`, and upon pressing ok, i would like to unwind to the first view controller.

However, anything i have read about such unwinding suggests `-(IBAction)`, which is system activated from storyboard buttons.

How do i unwind back from third to first view controller? i used

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueString sender:self];
```

but it crashes the application on attempting to navigate again

Comment: use [self.navigationcontroller poptorootviewcontroller] method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to use UIAlertView Delegate method as below,

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  //Using buttonIndex you could find whether OK or CANCEL is pressed and perform your popToRootViewController call.
  //Below on OK press then moving to root VC
  if (buttonIndex==0)
  {
     //OK is pressed...
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
  else{ 
     //CANCEL is pressed...
  }
}
```

Hope this help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewController]
```

will help you to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by @walle84 is great... but is not a Unwind Segue solution. If you want to use real Unwind Segues, follow this step by step.

In your FirstViewController.m file, add a `-reset:` method so that your code look like this:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

-(IBAction)reset:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    //you can do stuff here, if necessary
    //popToRootViewControllerAnimated doesn't allow it
    NSLog(@"Back to FirstViewController");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

In your ThirdViewController.m, set your `-alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method so that your code looks like this:

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@interface ThirdViewController () <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ThirdViewController

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyApp"
                                                      message:@"Do you want to reset to FirstViewController?"
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [message addButtonWithTitle:@"Perform Unwind"];
    [message show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myUnwindSegue" sender:self];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Then, in your Storyboard, select your `ThirdViewController` scene, click on the `Third View Controller` button and drag it to the `Exit` button (see image below). A pop up will appear. Select the `Reset:` link in it.

[image]

Once done, select your `unwind segue` button (see image below) and, in the Attributes Inspector, set its name to "myUnwindSegue" (see image below).

[image]

If you want to learn more about Unwind Segues, you can watch the WWDC 2012 session video "Adopting Storyboards in Your App" [starts at 38 minutes].